# Why Android animation is not freeze but return to start

Tags: android, animation

I search but cant find out any infromation how to freeze last state of animation like rotation or else.

I think than animation it's change some pictures with show's last state.

I have next xml animation file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="300"
        android:duration="5000" android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="10"
        >
    </rotate>
</set>
```

As you can see parameter toDegress it's setted to 300.
I use this animation xml to rotate text with next code

```
Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.myanimation);
                animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
                View animatedView1 = findViewById(R.id.rotatetext);
                animatedView1.startAnimation(animation1);
```

But then animation stops text not rotated state no 300 degrees, it's returns to 0 degress.

How i can do what animation freeze on last frame?

Keep It Simple Stupid

Read,read and read documentation

> When set to true, the animation transformation is applied after the
>   animation is over. The default value is false. If fillEnabled is not
>   set to true and the animation is not set on a View, fillAfter is
>   assumed to be true.
>
> Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement an AnimationListener and set to your animation object. write some code to change the View's state in the method onAnimationEnd().